# Android: How to handle drawing with canvas methods on different screen sizes?

Tags: android, canvas, pixel

I've been following the best practices for creating layouts for differing screen sizes as per this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I've now come to doing some drawing work using methods of the Canvas class:

eg.   canvas.drawLine(60, 320, 120, 320, linePaint);

Can any one help with how I am supposed to make those pixel values (60/120/etc) in to density pixels so that the line is scaled correctly? Otherwise the line will not appear as I intend, it'll be too far down and too long on smaller screens for example.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed it the first time going through the Android document; the necessary info is in section "3. Do not use hard-coded pixel values in your code" of the link in my original post.

Comment: So how did you end up drawing a link from these 2 points if you couldn't use pixels?

Comment: This is what I do: I figure out the size in px for a specific resolution and then calculate the ratio to the resolution. I can then use this value to calculate the actual px size for all resolutions.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a lot on this topic with Google, in fact here are two questions asked already that pretty much answer your question.

You want to use [dips.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

You also will probably want to convert [dips to pixels.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406449/does-setwidthint-pixels-use-dip-or-px)

Comment: I found the bit in the doc a few minutes after posting the question, thanks anyway.