# How to set margin for ImageView in pixels in android java?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, margin

I have a set of ImageViews whose BackgroundResource and LayoutParams will be defined in a separate xml file. The height, width, marginleft and margintop are given in pixels. The values are in respect to a 1024x600 pixel resolution screen. The code i'm using

```
    ImageView ImgV= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImgV_1);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams the_dimens = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50,50);
    the_dimens.setMargins(800,50,0,0);

    ImgV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bulbon);
    ImgV.setLayoutParams(the_dimens);
```

While the height and width seem to be rightly displayed in pixels, the margins are not. So how can I set the margin values to apply in pixels rather than whatever default units the below code takes. 
        `the_dimens.setMargins(800,50,0,0);`

The app is only for a 1024x600 device, so i'm not worried about resolution independent design.
Thanks.

Comment: the official docs for `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` say: `setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) Sets the margins, in pixels. [...]`

Comment: @pskink i've checked and measured the values in photoshop. they don't add up

Comment: @pskink if it isn't showing right in the emulator (which is 1024x600 res) i doubt it will be the case in the actual device.  I think im missing something here..

Comment: @pskink you are right. it is my mistake. the root relative layout had padding.   i think i should be more careful before posting here. thank you for your time :)

Comment: no problem really

Answer (score 0):

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914308/5343320)

```
int dpValue = 5; // margin in dips
float d = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int margin = (int)(dpValue * d); // margin in pixels
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```