# Android Notification Icon

Tags: android

I am giving notification by a background service. In notification i am displaying an image , image dimensions are 15*15. But when image is showed it automatically streches to big size , so it became blur. I haven't specified the image size in my program. Why this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because when specifying dimensions in Java it is automatically regarded as a pixel value.

You will have to implement a helper method somewhere, best in a helper class, which calculates and returns a density independent pixel value based on the provided pixel value.

The equation is `px = dip * (density / 160)` from which we get that `dip = px / (density/160)`.

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406449/does-setwidthint-pixels-use-dip-or-px/2406790#2406790) is even better actually.

Answer (score 10):

Refer status bar icon guidelines:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html

For **hdpi** status bar icon image should be 38px height (24x38),
**mdpi** - 16x25
**ldpi** - 12x19

Answer (score 8):

## The small icons

[Guildlines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html) says 24x24, that is for mdpi.

Applying the conversion `dp*density/160` you get these pixels resolutions:

**ldpi** 18x18
**mdpi** 24x24
**hdpi** 36x36
**xhdpi** 48x48

(The guidelines actually now list these 4 dimensions)

## Dynamically sized large icons

If you're creating an image, or resizing an image to fix the large notification image area, you can get the pixel dimensions like so:

```
int width  = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width);
int height = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height);
```

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.dimen.html#notification_large_icon_height