# Setting margin for an android view in float

Tags: android, view

For a view in android, I need to set margin in float value.

I'm using this, but I'm able to set margin in int only.

```
lp.setMargins(50, 35, 0, 0);
        starImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

How to pass float values for margin of a view ?

Comment: setMargins supports only pixel mentioned as integer only. If your intention is to convert from one unit to other, you can refer these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406449/does-setwidthint-pixels-use-dip-or-px

Comment: ok. I too read the documentation but I was thinking if there is any hack to pass float values. One method I figured out is to round up the float to next integer.