# Is `canvas.drawCircle` metho's radius in dp units?

Tags: java, android, canvas

Just a quick question. In android, the code for drawing a circle using `Canvas` is as below.

```
canvas.drawCircle (float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint)
```

I read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) to find out whether this `float radius` is dp units or any other unit. There is no such mentioning.

So, what is the unit this `float radius` is mentioned in? Is it dp units?

Comment: its sure pixel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406449/does-setwidthint-pixels-use-dip-or-px

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade: Thanks. Please provide comment as an answer

Comment: glad to help you. Please look into ans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In android, the code for drawing a circle using `Canvas` the `float` argument is in `pixels`.

**you say `float`, is the `float` a pixel representation.**

Below is the sample code for converting dp to px and px to dp.

> To convert dp to pixel.

```
public static int dp2px(Resources resource, int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,   dp,resource.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

> To convert pixel to dp.

```
 public static float px2dp(Resources resource, float px)  {
    return (float) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, px,resource.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

[Conversion Code is from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp)

Answer (score 0):

No. Float values will be in pixels. If you want (recommended) you can specify dp units in /res folder using dimen attribute

```
<dimen name="radius">12dp</dimen>
```